# transfer Windows 10 to a different Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10

I want to give my old Windows 10 machine to a relative.  The machine is licensed with a digital entitlement that is tied to my Microsoft Account.  I would like to transfer the entitlement to my relative's microsoft account, so that it is under his name instead.  How do I do that?

Comment: This an OEM machine?  If so just unlink your Microsoft Account and create a new local account.  Once you do that just link the new local account you created to the relative's  Microsoft Account and link the license to that Microsoft Account.  You can at that point remove the device from your Microsoft Account within a browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks -- this actually was a Retail Windows 7 license that took the free upgrade to Windows 10, so it now has a digital entitlement linked to it.

Comment: You can't take your license with you if you get rid of the hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not what I'm looking to do.  I want the license to stay with the hardware after I give the hardware away.  Right now, it's associated with my Microsoft Account, and I want it to not be associated so that the new owner can have it.  (there is a delete option in the microsoft account management screen, but I'm a little scared to use it, because it doesn't say whether it deletes the association or the license, and I don't want the O/S to become unlicensed)

Comment: If you disassociate the hardware from your account, then the license, is no longer tied to your account.  The license association feature is simply a way to avoid activation issues.

Comment: I know its been a while since this has been updated - But I'm in a similar spot - Bought a laptop for Dad, in the process of setting it up tied it to my Microsoft account... Need to do a format and clean install (because bloatware) before I hand it over - Worried windows won't activate once he signs in with his account... Don't want to leave my account tied to a machine I'm not going to be using... If @Ramhound 's answer worked, please mark it so.

Comment: @Abhishek - I never submitted an answer.

Comment: @Abhishek I never ended up transferring the entitlement, but it activated with no problem.  I'm not sure whether or not I will have problems in the future -- I just left that registration alone.  I didn't leave my account on the machine, and it is still activated.

Comment: Have you done this? I am trying to do the same but I am not sure how. Could you help me in this?